# Why does the title show above the colorbar but below the map?

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

Please see the codes below:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
m = Basemap(projection='cyl', resolution='c', llcrnrlat=0, urcrnrlat=90, llcrnrlon=0, urcrnrlon=360)
x, y = m(lon, lat)
scatter = m.scatter(x, y, c=theta, cmap='rainbow', norm=Normalize(vmin=math.floor(np.min(theta)/10.0)*10.0, vmax=math.ceil(np.max(theta)/10.0)*10.0), marker='o', s=20, edgecolors='none')

m.drawparallels(np.arange(0, 91, 20), labels=[1,0,0,0], linewidth=0.4)
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(0, 361, 40), labels=[0,0,0,1], linewidth=0.4)

x_special, y_special = m(lon[0], lat[0])
m.scatter(x_special, y_special, marker='*', s=50, edgecolors='black', linewidths=1.5)
x_special, y_special = m(lon[mintind], lat[mintind])
m.scatter(x_special, y_special, marker='^', s=40, c='blue')

m.drawcoastlines(linewidth=0.4)
#m.drawcountries(linewidth=0.2)
m.drawmapboundary(fill_color='white')

cax = plt.axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.65, 0.02])  # Define position and size of colorbar
cbar = plt.colorbar(scatter, cax=cax, orientation='horizontal')
cbar.set_label('Theta')
plt.title(date.strftime('%y%m%d%H'), fontsize=12)
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
save_path = os.path.join('/', *trajfile.split('/')[:-1], 'fig_' + date.strftime('%y%m%d%H') + '.png')
plt.savefig(save_path, bbox_inches='tight', dpi=300)
plt.close()
```

In the output figures (for reference, see the bottom), my title show only above the colorbar, but below the map. Why is it?

[image]

Actually I don't understand the logic of plotting in python. Like, I don't know why the handle 'm' is not explicitly used in the plot, but still it can be plot.

Answer (score 0):

`plt.title` will add a title to the last active `matplotlib.Axes` instance. In this case, you create an `Axes` instance for the colorbar (`cax`), then add the title, so the title gets added to that `Axes` instance.

One option would be to move `plt.title` above the creation of the colorbar, e.g. put it after `m.drawmapboundary()` in your code.

Another option would be to explicitly add the title to the `Axes` that the `Basemap` instance (`m`) is being drawn on. Something like:

```py
m.ax.set_title(date.strftime('%y%m%d%H'), fontsize=12)
```

should work here.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explainations!